# Connection timed out when call Rest API from Eclipse

Tags: java, client, restful-authentication

Help me! I have a restful API link, I used Postman tool call success, but when I code on eclipse a Restful client, it's fail. I tried on off proxy, but not success.

```
public class JersyGetClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://abc.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/accounts";
        String name = "thai.hoangan";
        String password = "123456a@";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        Client restClient = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                .header("OSvC-CREST-Application-Context", "asd")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (resp.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
        String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("response: " + output);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
>             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
>             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
>             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
>             at JersyGetClient.main(JersyGetClient.java:22)
>           Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>             at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>             at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>             at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>             at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
>             at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
>             at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>             at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>             at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>             at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
>             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
>             ... 5 more

Comment: Hi. Are you sure you are using the correct url here in eclipse that you've tried and tested in Postman?

Comment: I'm sure correct url :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I resolved, Just add:

```
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxytest.vcb");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```